# Bind to CheckBox Click event with in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm writing a WPF application using Caliburn.Micro. I want to update a name list based on checked items in a listbox with checkboxes.

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Value}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The IsChecked binding works so I could run a method to verify which elements has been checked and update the name list. My first approach were be to bind a command to the checkbox Click event or Checked/Unchecked, but I can't get it working...

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Value}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Click="{Binding UpdateNameList}" />
```

In my ViewModel:

```cs
public void UpdateNameList()
{
    // update list...
}
```

I get this error on runtime:

```
error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.
```

How can I bind to a checkbox click event with Caliburn.Micro? Or should I do this in another way?

Thanks

Comment: How can I pass object and RoutedEventArgs in the XAML-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the Action.Target to the parent view model using the `Action.TargetWithoutContext` attached property and use the `Message.Attach` to hook up the method. This should work:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Value}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
        cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
        cal:Message.Attach="UpdateNameList()" />
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!